# How to obtain incoming traffic/hits to MongoDB instance in real time?

Tags: mongodb

I have a 3-member replica set.

When there is any read/write from an application, I need to get the information lively like we `tail -f` a log file in unix.

Is there any method or command available?

Comment: yeah.. you can try mongotop (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) and mongostat (https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongostat/). Both are OS level commands.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to enable profiling for all operations.
See details here: https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

So, to enable profiling for specific database execute in shell:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

After this on each read/write operation an appropriate record will appear in **system.profile** collection with details about the query, time of execution, etc...

Also note that this would affect performance significantly, so don't use profiling for all queries on production environments